Does anyone know of a way to set off discord commands with webhooks?
I'm trying to set a command with discord webhooks with a bot I coded, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out if it is possible at all to activate commands via webhook. Other sources I've been looking up so far have just shown how to make a webhook manager instead of activating commands directly.
Trying to se if it's possible, if not, then I'll try a different road. Other sources have been dry
